# Sort array of object by particular member inside the object/class

Tags: java, arrays

Say I have a class that looks like this (get/set omited):

```
class InfoClass{

   String name;
   String place;
   double distance;

}
```

And I create an array of my class from within my main activity that looks like this:

```
InfoClass[3] myInfoClass;

myInfoClass[0].name = "venue one";
myInfoClass[0].place = "place one";
myInfoClass[0].distance = 11.23234;

myInfoClass[1].name = "venue two";
myInfoClass[1].place = "place two";
myInfoClass[1].distance = 9.2345643;

myInfoClass[2].name = "venue three";
myInfoClass[2].place = "place three";
myInfoClass[2].distance = 5.23432;
```

How can I sort my array (myInfoClass[]) so that it is ordered by the distance member?
i.e in the above example the array would be reversed because element [2] has the smallest distance and element [0] has the greatest distance?

Is there some function I can add to my class to do this or some other way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Modify your class and implement `Comparable`  interface if you don't want to use `Comparator` its also preferable when by default you want to provide sorting to `array/collection` of your objects then go for `Comparable`

```
class InfoClass implements Comparable<InfoClass> {

String name;
String place;
double distance;

@Override
public int compareTo(InfoClass o) {
    return new Double(this.distance).compareTo(new Double(o.distance));
}
```

and then you can sort them

```
Arrays.sort(myInfoClass)
```

Comment: this is a good answer, especially if you plan on sorting in several places in code.

Comment: you are right, thats the most OO solution. But i would use Double.compare(this.distance, o.distance); for comparing, otherwise you have at least n*log(n) unnecessary created Objects :)

Comment: Good catch @lee.O I didn't see that in there.

Answer (score 5):

this should work ..

```
    public static void main(String[] args){
    InfoClass[] dd = new InfoClass[3];

    Arrays.sort(dd, new Comparator<InfoClass>(){

        @Override
        public int compare(InfoClass arg0, InfoClass arg1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(arg0.distance == arg1.distance){
                return 0;
            }else if(arg0.distance < arg1.distance){
                return -1;
            }else{
                return 1;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `java.util.Arrays.sort()` and specify your own `Comparator`:

```
InfoClass[] myInfoClass = new InfoClass[3];

myInfoClass[0] = new InfoClass();
myInfoClass[1] = new InfoClass();
myInfoClass[2] = new InfoClass();

myInfoClass[0].name = "venue one";
myInfoClass[0].place = "place one";
myInfoClass[0].distance = 11.23234;

myInfoClass[1].name = "venue two";
myInfoClass[1].place = "place two";
myInfoClass[1].distance = 9.2345643;

myInfoClass[2].name = "venue three";
myInfoClass[2].place = "place three";
myInfoClass[2].distance = 5.23432;

Arrays.sort(myInfoClass,
            new Comparator<InfoClass>()
            {
                public int compare(InfoClass o1, InfoClass o2)
                {
                    if (o1.distance == o2.distance)
                    {
                        return 0;
                    }
                    else if (o1.distance < o2.distance)
                    {
                        return -1;
                    }
                    return 1;
                }
            });
```

Comment: Thank you for this, however I used the above answer since it allowed me to encapsulate the function within the class as suggested by the poster, thank you for this though I am sure it would have worked. +1

Answer (score 4):

You can use Arrays.Sort with a custom comparator like so:

```
Arrays.Sort(myInfoClass, new Comparator<InfoClass>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(InfoClass o1, InfoClass o2){
        if (o1==null && o2==null) return 0;
        if (o1 == null) return -1;
        if (o2 == null) return 1;
        return o1.distance.compareTo(o2.distance);
    }
});
```

**EDIT:** null checking for the win.

Answer (score 2):

```
Arrays.sort(myInfoClass, new Comparator<InfoClass>() {
  @Override
  public int compare(InfoClass o1, InfoClass o2) {
    return Double.valueOf(o1.distance).compareTo(o2.distance);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert array to ArrayList, then using `Collection.sort` method to sort the ArrayList.

Answer (score 1):

## Also sorting in descending order

Arrays.sort(aStudents, Collections.reverseOrder());

### Internally  Collections define method calls

```
`public static <T> Comparator<T> reverseOrder() {
    return (Comparator<T>) REVERSE_ORDER;
}
```

public int compare(Comparable c1, Comparable c2) {
            return c2.compareTo(c1);
        }`

Answer (score 0):

Hope , This example will help you **sort** class object base on **various fields**

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;


public class Main
{
    public static void main ( String [] args) throws IOException
    {

        Employee empList[] = new Employee [4];

        empList[0] = new Employee (8,"Kiran","Developer",15000);
        empList[1] = new Employee (18,"Krishna","DBA",35000);
        empList[2] = new Employee (3,"Pradeep","Tester",25000);
        empList[3] = new Employee (7,"Mithun","Admin",20000);




        Arrays.sort(empList);
        System.out.println("\nAfter Sorting Base On ID");
        for (Employee emp : empList)
            System.out.println(emp);


        Arrays.sort( empList , new EmployeeByDept() );  
        System.out.println("\nAfter Sorting Base On Department");
        for (Employee emp : empList)
            System.out.println(emp);


        Arrays.sort( empList , new EmployeeByName() );  
        System.out.println("\nAfter Sorting Base On Name");
        for (Employee emp : empList)
            System.out.println(emp);


        Arrays.sort( empList , new EmployeeBySalary() );    
        System.out.println("\nAfter Sorting Base On Salary");
        for (Employee emp : empList)
            System.out.println(emp);

    }
}

class EmployeeByDept implements Comparator<Employee>
{
    //compare() is mathod of Comparable Interface
    // Use When we want to sort on other field like Department  
    @Override
    public int compare(Employee emp1, Employee emp2)
    {
        return emp1.getDept().compareTo(emp2.getDept());
    }

}

class EmployeeByName implements Comparator<Employee>
{
    //compare() is mathod of Comparable Interface
    // Use When we want to sort on other field like Department  
    @Override
    public int compare(Employee emp1, Employee emp2)
    {
        return emp1.getName().compareTo(emp2.getName() );
    }

}

class EmployeeBySalary implements Comparator<Employee>
{
    //compare() is mathod of Comparable Interface
    // Use When we want to sort on other field like Department  
    @Override
    public int compare(Employee emp1, Employee emp2)
    {
        return ( emp1.getSalary() - emp2.getSalary());
    }

}



class Employee implements Comparable<Employee> 
{
    int $id  ;
    String $name ;
    String $dept ;
    int $salary ;

    public Employee(int id , String name , String dept , int salary)
    {
        this.$id = id;
        this.$name = name ;
        this.$dept = dept ;
        this.$salary = salary ;
    }


    public int getID () { return this.$id ; }
    public String getName () { return this.$name ; }
    public String getDept () { return this.$dept ; }
    public int getSalary () { return this.$salary ; }

    public String toString()
    {
        return  "[ "
                + "ID :: " + $id 
                + " Name :: " + $name 
                + " Department :: " + $dept 
                + " Salary :: " + $salary  
                + " ]";

    }

    //compareTo() is mathod of Comparable Interface
    //Use when you want natural sorting base on ID , Salary

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Employee emp)
    {
        return (this.$id - emp.$id);
    }


}
```