# Sorting an Array of Objects throws long[] error

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, object, arraylist

Im following the [MKyong sort examples](http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-object-sorting-example-comparable-and-comparator/).

I have the class `AGRinformesActivos` overriding `compareTo()` method to sort my class by `riesgoTotal` double.

```
public class AGRinformesActivos extends EntidadBase implements Comparable<AGRinformesActivos>{

private static final long   serialVersionUID    = -4341418821044868087L;

private String                  tipoActivo          = "";
private String                  codigo              = "";
private String                  denominacion        = "";
private int                     idAmenaza           = 0;
private double                  impactoTotal        = 0;
private double                  riesgoTotal         = 0;
private int                     valorPendiente      = 0;
ArrayList<Double>               impactoCuali        = new ArrayList<Double>();
ArrayList<String>               impactoCuanti       = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<Double>               riesgoCuali         = new ArrayList<Double>();
ArrayList<String>               riesgoCuanti        = new ArrayList<String>();
```

To order in asc Im using this `compareTo()` version: [Sort array of object by particular member inside the object/class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11050874/sort-array-of-object-by-particular-member-inside-the-object-class).

```
public int compareTo(AGRinformesActivos o) {
    return new Double(this.riesgoTotal).compareTo(new Double(o.riesgoTotal));
}
```

And this is my code:

```
    ArrayList <AGRinformesActivos> datosTotal = new ArrayList<AGRinformesActivos>();
    List listadoActTotal = manager.dameListadoActivos( Integer.parseInt(info.getIdtipoActivo().trim()), info.getCodigo().trim());
for( Object o : listadoActTotal ) {
                fila = (List) o;                    
                String codigoActivo = fila.get( 0 ).toString();             
                // If exists we obtain, if not exists we create.
                if (activosDimension.containsKey( codigoActivo )){
                    // If exists, obtain from activosDimension
                    informesActivo = activosDimension.get( codigoActivo );
                }else{
                    informesActivo = new AGRinformesActivos();
                    activosDimension.put( codigoActivo, informesActivo );
                    // Al objeto le añado tipoActivo, idActivo y Denominación
                    String tipoActivo = manager.dameNombreTipoActivo(info.getIdtipoActivo());
                    informesActivo.setTipoActivo( tipoActivo );
                    informesActivo.setCodigo( codigoActivo );
                    informesActivo.setDenominacion( fila.get( 1 ).toString() );
                    }
                    // Add impactoTotal and riesgoTotal
                    informesActivo.setImpactoTotal( Double.parseDouble( fila.get( 2 ).toString() ) );
                    informesActivo.setRiesgoTotal( Double.parseDouble(fila.get( 3 ).toString() ) );
                }

                informesActivo.getImpactoCuali().add( Double.parseDouble(fila.get( 5 ).toString() ) );
                informesActivo.getRiesgoCuali().add( Double.parseDouble(fila.get( 6 ).toString() ) );

                String gradoImp = dameRangoEconGrado(Double.parseDouble(fila.get( 5 ).toString() ));
                String gradoRiesg = dameRangoEconGrado(Double.parseDouble(fila.get( 6 ).toString() ));              
                if(gradoImp.equals("") ){
                    gradoImp = dameRangoEconGrado(1);
                }
                informesActivo.getImpactoCuanti().add( gradoImp );
                if(gradoRiesg.equals( "" )){
                    gradoRiesg = dameRangoEconGrado(1);
                }
                informesActivo.getRiesgoCuanti().add( gradoRiesg );

                if (!datosTotaltemp.contains( informesActivo )){
                    datosTotaltemp.add( informesActivo );
                    datosTotal.add( informesActivo );
                }
            }
Arrays.sort(datosTotal);

...
```

When the code reach to `Arrays.sort(datosTotal);` throws the error:

```
The method sort(long[]) in the type Arrays is not applicable for the arguments (ArrayList<AGRinformesActivos>)
] con causa raíz
java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    The method sort(long[]) in the type Arrays is not applicable for the arguments (ArrayList<AGRinformesActivos>)

    at com.dominion.procop.agr.struts.actions.AGRInformes.buscarActivosEmpty(AGRInformes.java:270)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
```

What am i doing wrong? `AGRinformesActivos` has a static long. is this the problem? why? in my compareTo im using the double of `riesgoTotal`.

Thank you in advance

Comment: You are sorting a `Collection`, not an array. Try `Collections.sort()` instead of `Arrays.sort()`.

Comment: ^^ and provide implementation of `Comparator<AGRinformesActivos, AGRinformesActivos>`: `Collections.sort(datosTotal, new Comparator<AGRinformesActivos, AGRinformesActivos>...`;

Comment: "The method sort(long[]) in the type Arrays is not applicable for the arguments (ArrayList<AGRinformesActivos>)"! You call the sort method with an `ArrayList`, but it is expecting a `long[]`. And ... don't run code with compilation errors.

Comment: @Keppil , changed and now works correctly. Can you post like an answer to give you the points? Thank you so much, i didnt see that.

Comment: @Victor: No need for a `Comparator` when the class implements `Comparable`.

Comment: @Keppil ^^ absolutely, I've overlooked that. Btw, you can still pass `Comparator` to `sort`, if you want some additional order ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are sorting a Collection, not an array. Try [`Collections.sort()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List)) instead of `Arrays.sort()`.

Answer (score 2):

your `datosTotal` reference is a collection, not an array. So you shouldn't use `Arrays` to sort it, but rather `Collections.sort`.

For efficiency's sake, I'd also recommend that you use

```
public int compareTo(AGRinformesActivos o) {
    return Double.compare(this.riesgoTotal,o.riesgoTotal);
}
```

Rather than creating two new Double objects for every comparison.

Answer (score 1):

`Arrays.sort` can not sort an ArrayList. Try to use [Collections.sort](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html)