# How would I be able to insert full data record after sorting a specific variable from each record?

Tags: java, arrays, binary-tree

so I'm creating a project that reads first name, last name, email, id number, color, and balance from a text file. This snippet of code successfully reads the id number from my array, sorts them into a binary tree, and prints only the id number. My question is how would i be able to get the rest of the info in there? No need to sort anything else, just getting my other info to be printed out after it's done sorting. Thanks again!

```
 public static void binaryTreeTable(Record[] objects) {

   treeNode tree = new treeNode();      
   int[] arr = null;

   for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
   arr = new int[]{objects[i].getnumID()};

   tree.treeins(arr);
   }

   tree.inorderRec(tree.root);     
 }
```

example of rest of info: John, Anderson, janderson@gmail.com, green, 0.1

Comment: How is your treeNode working ? You could store the full Record in the treeNode instead of an array with only the ID. But if your treeNode only accepts comparable objects, then you need to make your Record comparable if not already the case (implements Comparable) and adapt the compareTo method. Otherwise adapt the comparator used by your treeNode.
Btw, class name should start with Capital letter treeNode => TreeNode

Comment: If the idea is to sort all the records contained within the **objects[]** array based on the ID number in each record then implement Comparator in your **Record** class, create a overriden **compareTo()** method there then in your code just do: `Arrays.sort(objects);`. [This link may help you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11050874/sort-array-of-object-by-particular-member-inside-the-object-class) with this concept.